# How to call a method multiple times using RXJava - which operator do I use?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a function which does a network call to retrieve data, and I need to call it 5 times.  My method:

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
private fun getWeather(future : Int): String {
    var twitterURL = Constants.API_URL
    if (future > 0) {
        twitterURL += "future$future.json"
    }
        val urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse(Constants.API_URL).newBuilder()
        val url = urlBuilder.build().toString()

        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build()
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val response = client.newCall(request).execute()
        val body = response.body()
        return if (response.code() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

            body.string()
        } else {

            throw IOException("Bad Request: Server Response" + response.code().toString() + " " + response.message())
        }


}
```

I'd like to use the observable model doing something like:

```
private val array = DoubleArray(5)
Observable.fromArray(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) 
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())) 
      //observation on the main thread
      .subscribe(object:Subscriber<Int>(){
        override fun onCompleted() {
            calculateStandardDeviation(array)
        }

        override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
         //TODO : Handle error here
        }

        override fun onNext(t: Int?) {
         val string = getWeather(t)
         val gson = Gson()
         val weather = gson.fromJson(string,TwitterWeather::class.java)
         array[t-1] = weather.temperature

        }
       })
```

But really, onNext() runs on the main thread.  I want to run it all on the Schedulers.io() thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` tells on which scheduler will the subscribe callbacks, including `onNext` run. So just use `.observeOn(Schedulers.io())`

Check this article for more details:
https://medium.com/upday-devs/rxjava-subscribeon-vs-observeon-9af518ded53a

Conceptually, you need to move your network call from the subscription logic and make it Observable, something like this:

```
Observable.fromIterable(listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
            .flatMap { t ->
                Observable.fromCallable {
                    val string = getWeather(t)
                    val gson = Gson()
                    val weather = gson.fromJson(string, TwitterWeather::class.java)
                    weather.temperature
                }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            }.toList()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ temperatures ->
                calculateStandardDeviation(temperatures)
            }, {
                //TODO : Handle error here
            })
```

Comment: in '.flatMap { t ->
                Observable.fromCallable {
                    val string = getWeather(t)' t is a list, so this code will not work at all.

Comment: Ah, sorry, in rxjava 2 you need to use `fromIterable`

Comment: I've also moved `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to the `Observable.fromCallable`, I think it should work this way.